# Handcent SMS Delay sending feature

Tags: handcent-sms

I'm using the Handcent sms app on my Galaxy Nexus. I set the delay sending feature at `settings -> send message settings -> delay sending`. The feature worked for the next few messages but then stopped. Any ideas as to what may have caused this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In HandCent you can set delay settings for individual contacts. I'm pretty certain if you set this then the global setting will not override it so maybe you have set the delay to 0 on some contacts. Hope this helps.